# Additional source directories using Geany

Tags: linux, c++, geany

I'm using Geany in Ubuntu as an IDE for a C++ Project, and I want to use some external libraries (from Webots). However, I don't find the option to specify additional library paths (as one can find in Code::Blocks or Netbeans). Must I specify the paths manually as a build option? If so, how do I do it? I'm not exactly an expert at this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure this under Build -> Set build commands and options (this might differ from version of Geany you are using). The is not global library include path or such.